# Facebook Graph API Returning No Data For Test Insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve post insights for a test page's posts via the Facebook Graph API, when calling the API no errors are shown, but the insights data object comes back empty.

It's a test app in the developer portal, and the page and associated post was created by a test user.

There are interactions on the post by the same test user, and it can't be tested on the live app due to not having permissions.

I'm using the following url structure:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<pageId>_<postId>/insights?access_token=<pageAccessToken>&metric=post_impressions_unique&period=day
```

I get a HTTP200 response, and the following is returned:

```
{
    "data": [],
    "paging": {
        "previous": "<previousUrl>",
        "next": "<nextUrl>"
    }
}
```